# After redirecting in telegram bot nothing happened, why?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

`Hello everyone!
I want to create telegram bot , with python, where user click on "Follow" button and then redirecting to other telegram channel or group, but after redirecting nothing happened
here is my code

```
def start(update, context):
        keyboard = [[
             InlineKeyboardButton("Follow", url="https://t.me/+m6_EEmP8bkU2ODNi")
        ]]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        message = "Click for redirecting"
        update.message.reply_text(message, reply_markup=reply_markup)


    def button(update, context):
        query = update.callback_query
        query.answer()
        message = f"You have been redirected to {CHANNEL_ID} successfully!"

        # Edit the message to confirm that the user has been redirected
        query.edit_message_text(text=message)


    bot = Bot(TOKEN)
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

I have try several things, such as `send_message` etc, but still doesnt work,  `